# Flutter Local Notifications onSelectNotification Navigator not working if the app is already opened

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification

I use a Navigator in onSelectNotification in Flutter Local Notifications, if the app is already running when I set the notification the Navigator works fine, if the app is closed and opened it via the notification it works fine too because I use didNotificationLaunchApp.
**However**, if the app was closed after setting the notification and was opened again *before* receiving the notification, the Navigator doesn't work at all. any suggestions?

here is the code

```
void setNotification(
      BuildContext context, int id, int hours, int minutes) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
          if (payload != null) {
            debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
          }
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => PageScreen(
                title: payload,
              ),
            ),
          );
        });

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        'Notification Title',
        'Notification Body',
        _nextInstanceOfTime(hours, minutes),
        const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'daily notification channel id',
            'daily notification channel name',
            'daily notification description',
            playSound: true,
            sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('pop'),
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
          ),
        ),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        payload: 'Notification Payload',
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time);
  }
```

Comment: P.S. I tried to navigate using Get, still same problem